# Let's talk about size

Tags: partitioning

I'm going to install 12.04 LTS, and I'm wondering: How much disk space the root must have?

People said 6GB but Team Fortress 2 itself is 11GB. On Windows I needed like 180GB for C:\, but I don't have as many games on Linux. In fact in the next months I'll only have TF2 and Left 4 Dead 2 (about 25GB all togeter). So I calculate:

/ - 25GB + all software I usually install + ...?

It would be

/ - 140GB (all games including NOW and future Steam ones + system + software)

/home - 150GB (music, films, photos, series)

swap  - 4GB

Comment: swap 1,5 times ram, /root 8gb (for all installing -no games) /home rest(for music, games etc) because games and other stuff gets stored in /home, not /root, only the main programs are stored there.

Comment: FWIW, I only have TF2 installed in Steam. This is under /home as Dr_Bunsen says: ~/Steam is 15.5 GB.

Comment: My RAM is 4GB. So I'll put 6GB for Swap then.
Are all game files stored in /home? Because my Steam folder is not.

[link](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/4150/capturadetelade20121228.png)

Comment: Well yes, there is a Steam folder in my /home, but it's a LINK, that goes to another directory. Anyone knows where? [link](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/4150/capturadetelade20121228.png)

Comment: If you are not too sure about how to partition, use LVM.

Comment: I just need to know if Steam games go to /root or my /home folder (which I believe it's not the case)

Comment: According to your screenshot, steam link destination is in your home too (`/home/asd/.local/share/Steam`)

Comment: OK I guess I'll be OK then, making the /root 20GB, 6GB for swap and the rest to/home. Thank you all.

Comment: @Amanda @laurent @Dr_Bunsen Why you all talking about `/root`? It is the root user home directory. I think you mean `/` (the root directory).

Comment: True... it's `/`... it was this way in the question and I didn't pay attention... correcting where possible

Comment: @laurent Where do you see the location of the Steam directory from the screenshot? I don't use Nautilus so I'm not really sure how to read it. Anyway, in my case it's in ~/Steam i.e. /home/asd/Steam .

Comment: @Sparhawk it's in `Destino do link` (link endpoint) line (3rd line on the screenshot)

Comment: OIC. Thanks. I was looking at the first screenshot and didn't notice the other one. I was also confused, because the first (ScreenApps) seems to be a directory under /proc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry that much as partitions in linux are not frozen, you can change them without problems (considering your disk is not full...).

I think better using a small `/` (between 8G to 20G) and if you need to increase it later, you just define a new partition on empty disk space (or reduce one other partition to free space if you allocated everything) and mount it in the directory you need to expand.

Using LVM makes working with partitions faster (not always easier...) but you will be able to resize "partitions" (logical volumes) in a few seconds.

PS: from your screenshot, steam link destination is in your home too (`/home/asd/.local/share/Steam`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be fine with 20GB /root, since the most disk space is from games (home folder) and other personal stuff.

Comment: I believe so. I use 20GB /root too usually :)

Comment: obs: as said Eric Carvalho, it's `/` and not `/root`....